# Regular expression: match everything before From:

Tags: python-3.x, regex

Below is the text:

```
MISSING PAYMENT# 240103330000 || 2019101805166295



From: FLOW-One-Ticket@cwc.com <FLOW-One-Ticket@cwc.com>
Sent: 19 October 2019 5:24 AM
To: >Liberate - Helpdesk <Helpdesk.Liberate@CWC.COM>
S
```

In the output, I want something like this:

```
MISSING PAYMENT# 240103330000 || 2019101805166295
```

Comment: What about the empty lines - do you want them? Maybe you can just take the first line in the text, if other examples have the same format.

Comment: can you share more rows of data. If this is all you want, you can just do `text.split('From')[0]` to get the data

Comment: Can you give more examples? Based on the above, you could just match on the word "MISSING", which I'm guessing isn't what you want...

Comment: @mhawke empty lines are fine for me.

Comment: FLOW MISSING IVR PAYMENT 


From: FLOW-One-Ticket@cwc.com <FLOW-One-Ticket@cwc.com>
Sent: 02 October 2019 4:49 AM
To: >Liberate - Helpdesk <Helpdesk.Liberate@CWC.COM>
Subject: The Help Desk Task

Comment: @ManjY: please add the additional examples to your question as they are hard to work with as comments.

Comment: @mhawke thanks for the idea of just taking first line.. it serves my purpose which I did not realize at first

Answer (score 0):

Considering the limited sample data given you probably don't need regular expressions. You could simply split/partition the data on `From:`:

```
s, sep, _ = data.partition('From:')
```

and `s` would then be stripped to remove any leading and trailing white-space:

```
s = s.strip()
```

Or just take the first line of the data:

```
s = data.splitlines()[0].strip()
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace a match to this regex with a blank:

```
\s*From:[\s\S]*
```

eg

```
preFrom = re.sub(r'\s*From:[\s\S]*', '', paragraph)
```